# Java Array Object

Tags: java, arrays, jython

OS Windows 7 64-bit

I'm using a third party software to write scripts using jython. I'm able to create an array of component type "int" using "newInstance." I'm also able to retrieve elements at specific indices using "get." However, when I attempt to initialize array values using "setInt," I get an:

> IllegalArgumentException: Argument is not an array.

Why does it recognize the array when retrieving using get, but not when initiating using setInt?

```
    from java.lang.reflect import Array  
    arrayAsset = ['ExtRS', 'TPI', 'RRN', 'RRS', 'CCLN', 'CCLS', 'TPA', 'BAGN', 'BAGS', 'CP']  
    arrayCount = Array.newInstance(int, len(arrayAsset))  
    Array.get(arrayCount, 3)  
    Array.setInt(arrayCount, 3, 0)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used ArrayList instead of Array, not really a solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

What might be happening is that an array of Integer has been created.

in java

```
Object arrayCount = Array.newInstance(Integer.class, arrayAsset.length);
Array.setInt(arrayCount, 3, 0);
```

throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is not an array

while

```
Object arrayCount = Array.newInstance(Integer.class, arrayAsset.length);
Array.set(arrayCount, 3, 0);
```

will work

```
Object arrayCount = Array.newInstance(int.class, arrayAsset.length);
Array.setInt(arrayCount, 3, 0);
```

also works ok

Comment: I ended up importing ArrayList and using the 'set' and 'add' instructions. I should've updated my post, thank you for your input, BevynQ

Comment: Interesting case of autoboxing gone awry, eh?